# how to plot on the same bode plot a manual function plot() with function bode()?

Tags: transfer-function, matlab, bode-plot

I have a a transfer function that I plotted manually using Plot(w,abs(f1(w)))(plotted for a digital filer since I dont have signal toolbox) and I have another function that I used directly bode(f2(s))(analog filter). I would like to plot them both in one bode plot?

Comment: `bode(); hold on; bode(); hold off;`.

Comment: I know that one. but here I have plotted a transfer function with Plot() and and I have another one with bode(). so How I do Plot both at same bode plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a concept, but you could transform `f2` to be a transfer function, e.g. `tf2 = xx2tf(f2)` (if it's not already, since it seems you are already talking about `f2(s)`), and then just run:

```
[F2mag, F2phi, w] = bode(tf2);
```

and then use `mag`, together with `hold on/off` and `plot`:

```
plot(w, abs(f1)), "", w, F2mag);
```

Or the reverse, transform `f1` to `tf()` and then do as in the comment:

```
bode(...);
hold on;
bode(...);
hold off;
```

Comment: the first method shows error. I will try the second:>> plot(mag_3)
Error using plot
Data cannot have more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: @Yaakov Yes, the data comes out three-dimensional. You need to use `mag(:,:)` for that (only the third column or row has data).